# “Just a spoonful of sugar helps the medicine go down”

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions

Comment traduire en français les deux expressions suivantes ?

> **[a spoonful of sugar helps the medicine go down](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a_spoonful_of_sugar_helps_the_medicine_go_down)**
>   **[sugar the pill](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/sugar-the-pill)**
>
> Rendre moins désagréable une chose qui l'est (*to make something bad seem less unpleasant*, en anglais dans le texte)

Je connais l'expression « [avaler la pilule](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avaler_la_pilule) », mais il me semble qu'elle n'est pas équivalent. Il y a l'idée d'une chose dure à faire passer (comme dans *a bitter pill to swallow*), mais pas l'idée d'amélioration.

Je connais également la traduction donnée dans la chanson de Marry Poppins, et qui bat probablement tous les records de traduction atrocement litérale :

> Just a spoonful of sugar helps the medicine go down
>   ⇒ C'est le morceau de sucre qui aide la *médecine* à *couler*
>
> <sup>(Even Google Translate, though it was not invented back in 1964, provides a better one: *Juste une cuillerée de sucre contribue passer la pilule*)</sup>

[image: Mary Poppins]

---

Comment traduiriez-vous ces idée en un français correct ? Existe-t-il des expressions toutes faites ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Dorer la pilule

Autrefois, l'or était un des matériaux utilisés pour enrober une pilule de façon à en faire passer l'amertume. On trouve d'ailleurs aussi l'expression *gilded pill* en anglais, même si [elle est sur le déclin](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=gilded+pill%2Csugar+coated+pill%2Csugar+the+pill&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). En anglais *sugar the pill* est apparu au milieu du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle, en même temps que les techniques d'enrobage par du sucre, et *gilded pill* a décliné au fur et à mesure que l'usage des métaux a disparu, vers le milieu du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle. Quelques références :

- [Dorer la pilule, faire passer la pilule](http://www.mon-expression.info/avaler-la-pilule)
- [Pharmaceutical Tablet Coating](http://203.158.253.140/media/e-Book/Engineer/Maintenance/Coating%20Technology%20handbook/DK4036ch112.pdf) by Joseph L. Johnson (avec un peu de chimie)
- [Pills and Pill-Making](http://www.rpharms.com/museum-pdfs/07-pills-and-pill-making.pdf) (a Museum of the Royal Pharmaceutical Society information sheet)
- More anecdotal information on [gilded pills](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/43/messages/237.html)

On peut aussi dire ***faire passer la pilule***, pour suivre la construction de *a spoonful of sugar helps the medicine go down*. Ou, nettement plus rare, mais avec la même connotation qu'on fait un compromis plutôt que de passer en force, ***adoucir la pilule***.

[passer la pilule,dorer la pilule,adoucir la pilule http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=passer%20la%20pilule%2Cdorer%20la%20pilule%2Cadoucir%20la%20pilule&corpus=7&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2000](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=passer+la+pilule%2Cdorer+la+pilule%2Cadoucir+la+pilule&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3)

Comment: Intéressant, je n'avais jamais envisagé ce sens: pour moi "se faire dorer la pilule" avait le sens de ne rien faire. Merci, j'adore ce site !

Comment: @chepseskaf C'est une expression différente (et que pour ma part je ne connaissais pas avant de fouiller dans les expressions contenant le mot *pilule* hier).

Answer (score 4):

Je pense qu'il ne faut pas rester sur l'image de la pilule pour avoir une expression courante.

Je proposerais

> Faire passer la rampe.
>
> *La livraison gratuite, ça aide à faire passer la rampe du prix du sofa.*

Comment: Jamais entendu cette expression. Est-ce qu'elle est particulièrement présente dans certaines régions ?

Comment: Jamais entendue non plus

Comment: Bon, c'est local alors.

Comment: Local d'où, du coup?

Comment: Suisse, canton de Neuchâtel. Je ne sais pas local à quel point.